# Facebook Graph API : get satuses with photos on user's feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get **user's own posts** on  with images on his feed.

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/photos/uploaded
```

will get me the uploaded images but *without the status they were posted on*.

on the other hand,

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed?fields=message
```

will work just fine , but

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed?fields=message,attachments
```

is returning me this

> ```
> {
>   "error": {
>     "type": "http", 
>     "message": "unknown error", 
>     "status": 500
>   }
> }
> ```

(FYI as for v2.1 FQL is deprecated)

help?

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, you have to do `USER_ID/feed` and then filter out the posts that aren't images. In those kinds of objects, there is no `attachment` field. There isn't any way of filtering content in Graph API like you could do in FQL. You would have to get the post type which I'm pretty sure is the field `type`.